# Simplification of nonlinear differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given this nonlinear differential equation
$$
[(1+\epsilon y) y']'+ 2xy'= 0, \ \ \ 0 < x < \infty,
$$
why we can write it like the following?
$$
[(1+\epsilon y) (1+ \epsilon y)' ]' + 2x(1+\epsilon y)'= 0  ,  \ \ \ 0 < x < \infty
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that  $(1+\epsilon y)'=\epsilon y'$. So if  $\epsilon \neq 0$, we can cancel out $\epsilon$ from second equation to get back the first one.